# How to parse JSON string within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

There is a JSON string in a JSON object

```
{
 "abc": "{\n  \"_count\": 10,\n  \"_start\": 0,\n  \"_total\": 60\n }",
"success": true
}
```

I want to get the the the value of `abc` as JSON object in javascript.

Comment: please give us some details about the programming language you use... do you use jquery's getJSON function?

Comment: I want to capture it in javaascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(the_string).abc);
```

NOTE: Your JSON is invalid. Please correct it. It should be somewhat like the below:

```
{
 "abc": "{\n  \"_count\": 10,\n  \"_start\": 0,\n  \"_total\": 60\n}",
"success": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object is in a variable called `obj` then `obj.abc` will return the string value. As this is a JSON string encoding a JavaScript object you need to use JSON.parse to convert it : `var abc = JSON.parse (obj.abc);`. You now have access to the field vaues `abc._count`, `abc._start` and `abc._total`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var json = '{"abc": {"_count": 10,"_start": 0, "_total": 60 },"success": true}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.success);
console.log(obj.abc['_count']);
```